# How to interpret the LePus3 diagram for the visitor pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, diagram

The visitor pattern is depicted in LePus3 as shown in the picture below.

How does this diagram relate to the corresponding (Java) source code of the visitor pattern?

How do the artefacts in the diagram (client, Member, Ops, Elements, Aggregate, Visitors, square, triangle etc.) manifest themselves in the source code of the visitor pattern ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use code example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example), where:

Class `VisitorDemo` is the **Client** rectangle.

Classes `Wheel, Engine, Body, Car` is elements triangle, and `ICarElement` is their abstract parent with `void accept(ICarElementVisitor visitor);` as **Accept (abstract Visitor)** oval.

Classes `CarElementPrintVisitor, CarElementDoVisitor` are at the same time **Ops** oval and Visitors triangle with

```
void visit(Wheel wheel);
void visit(Engine engine);
void visit(Body body);
void visit(Car car);
```

as **Visit** oval.